# How can I parse an XML tag that has more than one attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I need help getting this XML to format so I can place it into an HTML element.

Here is my XML that is generated by the software:

```
<event status="coming up">
    <song title="Summer Of '69">
        <artist name="Bryan Adams" id="" url="">
            <info starttime="03:28:44" jazlerid="1997" playlisterid=""> 
                <media runtime="03:27">
                    <songurl></songurl>
                    <songbarcode></songbarcode>
                    <songcdkey></songcdkey>
                </media>
            </info>
        </artist>
    </song>
    <song title="Doing It All For My Baby">
        <artist name="Huey Lewis &amp; The News" id="" url="">
            <info starttime="03:32:11" jazlerid="2312" playlisterid=""> 
                <media runtime="03:25">
                    <songurl></songurl>
                    <songbarcode></songbarcode>
                    <songcdkey></songcdkey>
                </media>
            </info>
        </artist>
    </song>
    <song title="Freeway Of Love">
        <artist name="Aretha Franklin" id="" url="">
            <info starttime="03:35:36" jazlerid="1843" playlisterid=""> 
                <media runtime="05:44">
                    <songurl></songurl>
                    <songbarcode></songbarcode>
                    <songcdkey></songcdkey>
                </media>
            </info>
        </artist>
    </song>
    <song title="All I Need Is A Miracle">
        <artist name="Mike &amp; The Mechanics" id="" url="">
            <info starttime="03:41:21" jazlerid="2538" playlisterid="">   
                <media runtime="04:03">
                    <songurl></songurl>
                    <songbarcode></songbarcode>
                    <songcdkey></songcdkey>
                </media>
            </info>
        </artist>
    </song>
    <song title="Sweet Nothing PLAY !!!!">
        <artist name="Calvin Harris with Florance Welsh" id="" url="">
            <info starttime="03:45:33" jazlerid="5362" playlisterid="">   
                <media runtime="03:26">
                    <songurl></songurl>
                    <songbarcode></songbarcode>
                    <songcdkey></songcdkey>
                </media>
            </info>
        </artist>
    </song>
</event>
```

I know how to get it into my web page with this code:

```
  function loadnext() 
  {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
      document.getElementById('ntn').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "AirPlayNext.xml"+ ((/\?/).test("AirPlayNext.xml") ? "&" : "?") + (new Date()).getTime());
  xhttp.setRequestHeader( 'CacheControl', false );
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The code above gets the data and inserts into a HTML tag. I also added a date routine to force update (which prevents caching of the xhr in all browsers)

I know how to parse one attribute, but how do you parse all of the attributes out of a single xml tag?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, the question is tagged as [tag:xslt] but shows only some Javascript code to load an XML document in the browser. You talk about how to "parse all of the attributes out of a single xml tag", in general as you already do use *`XMLHttpRequest`* the browser does the XML parsing of the response for you and gives you the `responseXML` document as an XML DOM document object. How does your code "to parse one attribute" look like? Perhaps then it becomes clearer what you want to do with the XML data.

Comment: I need to take the information out of each attribute listing and place them into an html table for a web page. I don't know xml, nor the proper method to get the data out of the tags. right now, I can bring it up to the page but how do I format the xml to html,  use jquery? xslt? I have no idea. I guess I could make a php substr filter for it, but there should be a more elegant way to format it for a html page.

Comment: XSLT is a programming language well-suited to transform XML to HTML, there are online tutorials, there are free books available, like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm. Integrating it on the client is another problem but as you mention PHP you can as well do it on the server (where you then have only one API http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php instead of having to deal with browser incompatibilities).

Comment: I was thinking maybe going to the php route. I do have a linux server at the station.  Thank you @MartinHonnen for some ideas. Maybe having the production computer auto ftp the file to the linux server, it format it to html then up load it and then append it with xhr on the web page side. It sucks that this file is formatted differently than the "now playing" xml file because that was just up load and use css tags to format since the data was between opened and closed tags like a normal xml file I see in tutorials.

Comment: I can see the php would be a little efficient for parsing since the code would be: $tittle=$xml->Event->Song['tittle']; after the xml file is loaded into a php variable. The challenge there would be making the associated loop to strip out the data, then it would be down hill after that.